# object has no attribute outside of class

Tags: javascript, python, html, class

Hello I'm working on a project and after making a class I'm unable to access the methods outside in order for the functionality to work. I'd like to use the methods inside my class to add or take away from the balance and display.

Any help would be great

Code:

```
class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self, full_name, account_number, routing_number, balance):
        self.full_name = full_name
        self.account_number = account_number
        self.routing_number = routing_number
        self.balance = balance

        def deposit(amount):
            self.balance += amount
            print("\n Amount Deposited:", amount)

        # Function to withdraw the amount
        def withdraw(self):
            amount = float((input("Enter a amount")))
            if self.balance >= amount:
                self.balance -= amount
                print("\n You Withdrew", amount)
            else:
                print("\n Insufficient funds.")
                self.balance - 10
        # Function to display the amount

        def display_balance(self):
            print("\n You have ", self.balance)

        def add_interest(balance):
            interest = balance * 0.00083

        def print_receipt():
            print(full_name)
            print("Account Number: " + account_number)
            print("routing number: " + routing_number)
            print("balance:" + balance)


# creating an object of class
s = BankAccount("Bob", 00000, 0000, 1)

# Calling functions with that class object
s.withdraw(22)
s.display()
# Calling functions with that class object
```

Comment: `display` method is not defined. I believe `s.display()` should be `s.display_balance()`

Comment: @sytech same issue. "'BankAccount' object has no attribute 'display_balance'"

Comment: All your methods are dedined inside `__init__()` method, just move them outside the `__init__()` It's just problem with the indentation level. Then you will have other problem though

Answer (score 1):

You're missing references to self in your class methods. Try this:

```py
class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self, full_name, account_number, routing_number, balance):
        self.full_name = full_name
        self.account_number = account_number
        self.routing_number = routing_number
        self.balance = balance

        def deposit(self, amount):
            self.balance += amount
            print("\n Amount Deposited:", amount)

        # Function to withdraw the amount
        def withdraw(self):
            amount = float((input("Enter a amount")))
            if self.balance >= amount:
                self.balance -= amount
                print("\n You Withdrew", amount)
            else:
                print("\n Insufficient funds.")
                self.balance - 10
        # Function to display the amount

        def display_balance(self):
            print("\n You have ", self.balance)

        def add_interest(self, balance):
            interest = self.balance * 0.00083

        def print_receipt(self):
            print(self.full_name)
            print("Account Number: " + self.account_number)
            print("routing number: " + self.routing_number)
            print("balance:" + self.balance)
```

Also, you're calling a `display()` function that is not defined in your class. I believe you mean to use `display_balance()`.

Finally, when you make your call to the `withdraw()` function you are entering a value as an argument to the function but the function is not designed to accept any arguments. The way you have it written it asks for user input on the command line. If you want it to accept arguments instead you can redefine it like this:

```py
# Function to withdraw the amount
def withdraw(self, amount):
    if self.balance >= amount:
        self.balance -= amount
        print("\n You Withdrew", amount)
    else:
        print("\n Insufficient funds.")
        self.balance - 10
```